# Create an n-gram list from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to create an N-gram list from an ArrayList containing an amount of words. 
My current code looks like this:

```
    public void ngram(int n){
    int i = 0;
    for(String a : arraylist){
        if (i < arraylist.size() - 2) {
    ngramlist.add(arraylist.get(i) + " " + arraylist.get(i+1) + " " + arraylist.get(i+2));
    i++;
    }
    }
    System.out.println(ngramlist);
}
```

Where arraylist is the list with words and ngramlist is the list I want to create from arraylist. 
This code works, but not as I want to. If i enter a text like "cat dog birds chair table" the output would be "cat dog birds, dog birds chair, birds chair table". 
What I'm trying to accomplish though is to be able to enter an amount of words I want to add in a row, using the variable n. So if I put 2 as n, it would be "cat dog, dog birds, birds chair, chair table" instead.

So I want my code to be something like this:

```
    public void ngram(int n){
    int i = 0;
    for(String a : arraylist){
        if (i < arraylist.size() - n) {

    (add all the words between i and i+n, so if n is 3 it adds 0-2, 1-3, 2-4 etc.)

    i++;
    }
    }
    System.out.println(ngramlist);
}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can just use another loop inside your main one:

```
String ngram = "";
for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)
     ngram += arraylist.get(i + j) + " ";
ngram += arraylist.get(i + n - 1);
ngramlist.add(ngram);
```

I agree this could be inefficient because it creates a lot of Strings, but otherwise it's simple and it should work. (edit: actually, I'm thinking, if these are stored in the string pool it probably shouldn't even be so bad)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StringBuilder`:

```
for(String a : arraylist){
    if (i < arraylist.size() - n) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
            sb.append(arraylist.get(i+j)).append(" ");
        }
        sb.append(arraylist.get(i+n-1));
        ngramlist.add(sb.toString());
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think line `sb.append(arraylist.get(i+n));` is not needed as it is adding one more item from the arrayList , which is not correct. I ran it for n=2, but it outputs results as n=3. By removing that line it works perfect!

Comment: This way you will also get a space next to your last word in the n-gram (that's what that line does, it adds the last word but without space). A better solution would be to stop the loop one step earlier: `for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++)`, and then replace the line after the loop with `sb.append(arraylist.get(i+n-1))`.

Comment: @Sudhir I was confused by your first code snippet, which I interpreted as `n==2`, but apparently that's `n==3`...